# Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

I want to select 12 posts from `posts` table. If there is no 12 of them, I need to select the missing from `parchive` table.

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts where status='public' and user='public' order by inde asc limit 12 offset " . $offset);
$count1 = $stmt->rowCount();
if ($count1 < 12){
    $diff = 12 - $count1;
    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts where status='public' and user='public' order by inde asc limit 12 offset " . $offset . 
    " union select * from parchive where status='public' order by date desc limit " . $diff);
}
```

Error:
`General error: 1221 Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY in...`

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need  limited  and order select for union add  a couple of ()  around the select out the union

```
  $stmt = $db->query("(SELECT * 
              FROM posts 
              where status='public' and user='public' 
              order by inde asc limit 12 offset " . $offset . 
          ")  union  ( select * 
          from parchive where status='public' order by date desc limit " . $diff .")");
```

in this way the the UNION work on result set and not on the direct select